# How to get all subfolder names consisting of uppercases only?

Tags: shell, find, directory

How to get the folders in a parent folder, the names of which are composed of A-Z, without lowercases, underscore, dot or any other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of 'parent folder' is a little confusing, this will find all the folders (actually directories) in a given path, without traversing the entire tree, that are made up only of A-Z.

`find /given/path -type d -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*"`

For example, to do the current directory,

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*"`

To do the parent of the current directory,

`find .. -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*"`

To do the current directory and every directory below it,

`find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*"`

Sample output,

```
tony@trinity:~$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*"
./AA
./TEST
```

Now, if you need to remove the `./` from the output, you can just `cut` it out afterwards.

```
tony@trinity:~$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/[A-Z]*" | cut -c 3-
AA
TEST
```

But this only works if you don't traverse down the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
ls -1 | grep -w "[A-Z]*"
```

Comment: This colourises the output on my machine, but doesn't just return the uppercase directories?

Comment: at the risk of outputting things other than directories

Comment: Agreed, both. My bad!